# AlphaData alternative in Matlab

Tags: linux, matlab, matlab-figure, alpha-transparency

In Matlab I'm plotting a matrix (let's call it M) using imagesc over an image using imshow. I would like M to have a degree of transparency so I can actually see the image below. This is what I'm doing:

```
    imshow(img); hold on;
    h = imagesc(M); 
    set(h,'AlphaData',0.4); % set transparency to 40%
```

However, the last line generates an error when running it on Linux. I've been trying to solve it but nothing seems to work. I wonder if there is an alternative to the "AlphaData" property to make it transparent. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Matlab R2014a and Java 1.7 on a Linux CentOS 6.6

Comment: What does `get(gcf,'renderer')` return? (This will tell you the current renderer). And `set(gcf,'renderer')`? (This is the list of possible renderers). Try setting the renderer to one different than the one you are currently using. Some renderers don't support transparency. (On Windows, I think only `'opengl'` does)

Comment: Have you tried `alpha(.4)` or even `set(h, 'alpha',.5);` ?

Comment: Thanks, Luis. That has solved it!

Comment: I just needed to start matlab from terminal calling "matlab -softwareopengl" to change to OpenGL renderer

Comment: Post that as an answer? It may be helpful for Linux users having the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) suggested, I just needed to change the renderer. You can:

```
>get(gcf,'renderer'); % to see which render engine is Matlab using
>set(gcf,'renderer'); % to get a list with all the possible renderers in your machine
```

So, at least in Linux, to change the renderer it's necessary to start Matlab from terminal by calling it as:

```
matlab -softwareopengl
```

Once this is done, setting transparency in an specific plot, as shown in the description of the question, is possible.